# Maven: I Don't want to download default junit jar in .m2 directory

Tags: java, maven, junit, windows-10

I deleted and clean all files and folders under **c:\users\myuser.m2\repository** directory.

Then I ran `mvn clean install` command with a simple **pom** like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.daniel</groupId>
    <artifactId>hola</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.7.0</maven.compiler.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How can I avoid or exclude the download of the folder *junit* and its files under **.m2** directory?

[image: .m2 junit directory]

Comment: Did you try with `-DskipTests` ?

Comment: *How can I avoid or exclude the download of the folder junit and its files under .m2 directory?* - Please explain why do you want this.

Comment: Hi @Mureinik. I tried a <code>mvn clean install -DskipTests=true</code> and the junit folder is downloaded again after deleted all under .m2 directory.

Comment: Hi @lexicore: I don't want the junit folder and all its files to be downloaded when I delete everything under .m2 and execute a mvn clean install again. 
Junit 3.8.1 is downloaded as default by maven when someone run mvn clean install at first time in a computer. I don't want this "default" download.

Comment: @dani77 You have reiterated on what you want but you did not explain, *why* do you want it. Which was my question.

Comment: @lexicore: For academic reasons and also because I do not want artifacts that I do not use.
It is bothering me a little bit.

Comment: If you run `mvn clean install` the maven-surefire-plugin will be triggered during the life cycle to run the tests. It does not matter that you gave `-DskipTests=true` cause maven-surefire-plugin or better the junit provider needs unit as a dependency. If you like to prevent that you have to use `mvn clean compile` instead. The real question is: Why do you try that? What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to change the default directory in which maven plugins are downloaded you can use the `<localRepository>` tag which must be put inside the `<settings>` tag

```
<settings>
    <localRepository>path/to/your/directory</localRepository>
<settings>
```

[you can also take a look similar options on the maven documentation that could be of help.](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

(for the sake of simplicity and readability I omited the settings tag attributes)

Comment: @khmarbaise you're right I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @BrianJerez the question is: why maven downloads junit 3.8.1 by default?